# Forecasting quantity for each product

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting

How to apply the forecast to predict for 3 months the quantity of each product with the data below.
It is not a multivariate forecast because we will not forecast the product, but only the quantity of each product. Should I separate each product into a Dataframe and apply the forecast to each product, or have another approach to solve this like use the product in a multivariate approach?

```
    Date |  ProductID | Quantity 
1/4/2019 |  SGX2134   | 53
1/4/2019 |  DLY0984   | 25
5/4/2019 |  FBDI863   | 1
.
.
.
3/5/2019 | SGX2134   | 33
7/5/2019 | DLY0984   | 4
```

Comment: Are purchases of different products correlated or independent?

Comment: @LukaszTracewski They are independent. The problem is that some products do not have much data, such as a product that only has a quantity in 1 day. How to forecast for 3 months of products that have little historical data?

Comment: Group them by product then and proceed as usual for univariate time series.

Comment: @LukaszTracewski You mean, separate products into different dataframes and forecast for each product separately? Thanks for your answers

Comment: Exactly, that's by far the best approach. Mind that likely you will have, next to seasonality, also special events like holidays. This can turn your problem into a multivariate one.

Comment: Thank you! I will consider it!

Answer (score 1):

Since the products are independent, the data frame can be grouped by `ProductID` and each of the series forecasted independently.